# Passing async function to my React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a custom component, and try to pass an async function to it in this way:

```
// compiler error: ';' expected 
export const MyDialog = ({ onDeleting: async (id: string) => Promise<void> }) => {
  ...
  return <>
      ...
     // Compiler error: Cannot find name 'onDeleting'.
     <Button onClick={onDeleting}>OK</Button>
  <>
}
```

But I get two errors:

1. The component's arrow function expect a semicolon somewhere
2. The Button onclick callback complains `Cannot find name 'onDeleting'.`

Where do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You used a wrong syntax

```
export const MyDialog = ({ onDeleting }: { onDeleting: (id: string) => Promise<void> }) => {
  ...
  return <>
      ...
     // Compiler error: Cannot find name 'onDeleting'.
     <Button onClick={onDeleting}>OK</Button>
  <>
}
```

Comment: With your syntax, I get one more error `Cannot find name 'async'`

Comment: I don't see `async ` in this code

Comment: `async` is mentioned in my code if you check or search :)

Comment: But it's not in my code, so why do you get this error now?

Comment: I don't get you, if not in your code (yes, it is not in your code), why it is an answer to my question which requires an async function in custom component? I mean if you check my question title, async is one key thing for it.

Comment: `async` is a syntactic sugar for a function that returns a promise. `Promise<void>` says that the function will be async. There is no `async` type in typescript

Comment: Right. Sorry about that. I removed `async` but get a new error `No overload matches this call.` it is long so I only write the 1st line of error. This error is on the `onClick={onDeleting}` line

Comment: @user842225 there is usually a longer explanation after the error name explaining why the types don't match. I guess that `onClick` doesn't pass any aguments

Comment: Could you please provide a playground link? So that I can easily check your answer? Thanks in advance